# Why magento return query in load collection

Tags: magento, collections, product

I will use a collection of product but when I load a product with id 20 Magento return a SQL query.

Code :

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->setPageSize(6);

echo $products->load(20)->getname();
```

SQL Query :

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = 1) LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling load on a collection the parameter gets ignored. Load function on collections just executes the query if it hasn't already beend executed.

You could either use model:

```
$product = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( 20 );
```

Iterate over the collection:

```
foreach( $products as $product ) {
    $product->load( $product->getId() ); // it would be better to add attributes to collection if possible instead of loading the product here
}
```

Get first item from collection:

```
$product = products->getFirstItem();
$product->load( $product->getId() );
```

Or get item from collection by Id:

```
$product = $products->getItemById( 20 );
$product->load( $product->getId() );
```

Note that in all the situations load is called on product and not on collection.

Note also that you should avoid load function call on product if possible (performance hit) and add required attributes to collection with call to `addAttributeToSelect` instead.